# Variable "url_resources" does not exist. Here I'm trying to display the values of form that i just entered above

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7SLv.png)Variable "url_resources" does not exist. Here I'm trying to display the values of form that i just entered above. It always fetches me the same error. I want it to be displayed on the same page without getting navigated to a different one. i have created 3 textboxes for displaying the appropriate fiels as you can see in the twig code.

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace UrlResourceBundle\Controller;

use UrlResourceBundle\Entity\url_resources;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class DefaultController extends Controller

{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="todo_list")
     */
    public function listAction()
    {

    $urls_resources = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('UrlResourceBundle:url_resources')
        ->findAll();

        return $this->render('todo/index.html.twig', array(
'urls_resources' => $urls_resources
            ));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/todo/create", name="todo_create")
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {

        $url_resources = new url_resources;
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($url_resources)




            ->add('title', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px')))
            ->add('url', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px')))
            ->add('description', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px')))


            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => "Create",'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px')))





             ->getForm();




        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())





        {




//Get Data
            $title = $form['title']->getData();
            $url = $form['url']->getData();
            $description = $form['description']->getData();





            $url_resources->setTitle($title);
            $url_resources->setUrl($url);
            $url_resources->setDescription($description);


            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($url_resources);
            $em->flush();









            $this->addFlash(
                    'notice',
                    'Entry Created'
                );








return $this->redirectToRoute('todo_create');

return $this->redirect($request->getUri());

        }
         return $this->render('todo/create.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView()
            ));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/todo/edit/{id}", name="todo_edit")
     */
    public function editAction($id, Request $request)
    {

       $url_resources = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('UrlResourceBundle:url_resources')
        ->find($id);





            $url_resources->setTitle($url_resources->getTitle());
            $url_resources->setUrl($url_resources->getUrl());
            $url_resources->setDescription($url_resources->getDescription());




        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($url_resources)


            ->add('title', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px')))
            ->add('url', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px')))
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px')))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => "Update",'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px')))

             ->getForm();


        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {

//Get Data
            $title = $form['title']->getData();
            $url = $form['url']->getData();
            $description = $form['description']->getData();



             $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
             $url_resources = $em->getRepository('UrlResourceBundle:url_resources')->find($id);

            $url_resources->setTitle($title);
            $url_resources->setUrl($url);
            $url_resources->setDescription($description);






            $em->flush();







            $this->addFlash(
                    'notice',
                    'Entry Updated'




                );
return $this->redirectToRoute('todo_list');

        }

        return $this->render('todo/edit.html.twig', array(
'url_resources' => $url_resources,
'form' => $form->createView()
));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/todo/details/{id}", name="todo_details")
     */
    public function detailsAction($id)
    {

          $url_resources = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('UrlResourceBundle:url_resources')
        ->find($id);

        return $this->render('todo/details.html.twig', array(
'url_resources' => $url_resources

));
    }


   /**
     * @Route("/todo/delete/{id}", name="todo_delete")
     */
    public function deleteAction($id)
    {

          $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
             $url_resources = $em->getRepository('UrlResourceBundle:url_resources')->find($id);

            $em->remove($url_resources);
             $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash(
                    'notice',
                    'Entry deleted');


                    return $this->redirectToRoute('todo_list');

        }




    }
```

**Twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}

<h2 class="page-header">Create</h2>
{{form_start(form)}}
{{form_widget(form)}}

<ul class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item">Title: {{url_resources.title}}</li>
<li class="list-group-item">URL: {{url_resources.url}}</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Description: {{url_resources.description}}</li>
</ul>

{{form_end(form)}}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: can you give the exact error message ? we don t know where it happens

Comment: i have added the screenshot of error...pls see top of the question.. thankyou...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it s undefine, because you don't passe it,

pass it to your render

```
  return $this->render('todo/create.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'url_resources' => $your variable name
        ));
```

Comment: now the error is gone..but the form values are not getting displayed in the box below(box declared in twig). ie the Title, Url and Description fields are empty in the webpage...

Comment: that s another error, please mark the answer as solved and open another issue